# Add Legend to Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms, legend

I have a leaflet map that consists of various wms layers representing different years.

I am trying to add a legend to my leaflet map but with my own custom hex colours instead of trying to use a layer in the map (as my legend is more broad) This is the sample code from leaflets website.

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
    grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
    labels = [];

    // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
}

return div;
};

legend.addTo(map);
```

Is there anyway to adapt this to my own 5 class hex(colors) legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legend does not depend on the existence of any particular layer. The part that you are missing here is a `getColor` function. Copying the one from [the tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) in question:

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           d > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           d > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           d > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           d > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           d > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}
```

You see that the breaks are the same as the `grades` specified in the legend control:

```
grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000]
```

If you adjust these breakpoints to your needs and set the colors accordingly, you will have the legend you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {

var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
labels = ['<strong>Categories</strong>'];
categories = ['Road Surface','Signage','Line Markings','Roadside Hazards','Other'];

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        div.innerHTML += 
        labels.push(
            '<i class="circle" style="background:' + getColor(categories[i]) + '"></i> ' +
        (categories[i] ? categories[i] : '+'));

    }
    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: should that comma after the labels list be a semcolon?

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting.